# C++ const char* input

Tags: c++

I am 'rebuilding' the .NET framework but for C++ (without using the .NET framework so it will also work on other OS).

This means I will create a class Console, and then if the method is called WriteLine in .NET framework, I call it all lowercase, split by _ (like this: write_line)

I am now busy with read_line but I am stuck.

I tried several things already:

```
static const char * read_line()
{
    char input[256];
    std::cin >> input;
    return std::string(input).c_str();
}

static const char * read_line()
{
    char input[256];
    std::cin >> input;
    return input;
}
```

But both of them give out some weird characters. The first method gives out (for example):

Your name is: ╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠
╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠
╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠α├¶☼☺╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠        ╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠≡
      ╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠ and your age is: ╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠
╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠
╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠α├¶☼☺╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠
    ╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠∞       ╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠

The second one gives out:

Your name is: ►       ╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠ and your age is:     ╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠

What am I doing wrong? I can't get the method to return as a char array either.

Comment: You're returning dangling pointers.

Comment: std::string(input).c_str() is valid only until the created std::string is deleted or modified.

Comment: no no please not again... it hurts...

Comment: I always wondered how downvoting newcomers questions could be helpful...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're returning a pointer to a local array, which is destroyed when the function returns. The best solution is to return a string object:

```
std::string read_word() {
    std::string input;
    std::cin >> input;
    return input;
}
```

Note that I also changed the function name to match what it does. If you actually want a line, then you want

```
std::string read_line() {
    std::string input;
    std::get_line(std::cin, input);
    return input;
}
```

If you really think you want to return a pointer, then think again. You almost certainly don't.

If you still really think you do, then you could return a pointer to a static variable, which lasts as long as the program:

```
// Danger: the returned pointer is only valid until the next call.
// Danger: do not call from multiple threads.
// Danger: any line longer than 255 characters will cause dreadful calamity.
char const * read_line() {
    static char input[256];
    std::cin.getline(input);
    return input;
}
```

or dynamically allocate an array, and hope the caller remembers to delete it:

```
// Danger: the returned pointer must be deleted (with `delete[]`) after use
// Danger: any line longer than 255 characters will cause dreadful calamity.
char const * read_line() {
    char * input = new char[256];
    std::cin.getline(input);
    return input;
}
```